Extracting filenames from a list of paths in a Word document
I want to provide a search and replace query to my colleagues who have MS Word that will take the results of a Copy Path operation and turn it into a list of just the filenames. It can use wildcards in Advanced Search but nothing more complicated. Word wildcards are similar to but not the same other versions of regex that I have used.
So this:
"C:\Users\username\folder\anotherfolder\file (1).JPG"
"C:\Users\username\folder\anotherfolder\file (2).JPG"
"C:\Users\username\folder\anotherfolder\file (2).JPG"

Becomes this
file (1).JPG
file (2).JPG

Possible? Not possible? Maniacal laughter at the thought. . . .
TIA
